# How to map in Polars

Tags: python-polars

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'],
        'value': [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 0, 1]

    }
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'type': ['β', 'β', 'β'],
        'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'],
        'value': [100, 233, 666]
    }
)

df3 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'],
        'value': [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 0, 1],
        'type_β': ['β', 'β', 'β', 'β', 'β', 'β', 'β', 'β', 'β'],
        'value_β': [100, 233, 666, None, 100, 233, 100, 233, 666]
    }
)

print(df1, df2, df3)
```

**How can we concatenate df1 and df2 into df3 based on the date?**

Missing dates do not need to be filled, default None，
Please use Polars（polars version = 0.17.11）

Comment: It's a left join: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/transformations/joins/#left-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to concat. Think of concat as adding rows, not combining datasets. You want a join.

I think your example output is off just a touch though.

On the surface you want to do this:

```
df1.join(df2, on='date', how='outer', suffix="β")
```

which results in

```
shape: (9, 5)
┌──────┬────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ type ┆ date       ┆ value ┆ type_β ┆ value_β │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str    ┆ i64     │
╞══════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 3     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 5     ┆ β      ┆ 666     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 7     ┆ null   ┆ null    │
│ B    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 8     ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ B    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 9     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 12    ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 0     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1     ┆ β      ┆ 666     │
└──────┴────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┘
```

You can see how this has a null value in the `type_β` column in the same row that you have a null in the `value_β` column so I think that was a typo or else you want more functionality than you said.

If you do want to fill in `type_β` then you can follow up with

```
df1.join(df2, on='date', how='outer', suffix="_β") \
    .with_columns(type_β = pl.col('type_β').forward_fill())

shape: (9, 5)
┌──────┬────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ type ┆ date       ┆ value ┆ type_β ┆ value_β │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str    ┆ i64     │
╞══════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 3     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 5     ┆ β      ┆ 666     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 7     ┆ β      ┆ null    │
│ B    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 8     ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ B    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 9     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 12    ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 0     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1     ┆ β      ┆ 666     │
└──────┴────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┘
```

The distinction between `how='outer'`, `how='left'`, and the default `how='inner'` is how values should be treated that aren't in both `df`s that are being joined.

inner joins will only return rows where values in the column to be matched exist on both sides of the join

left joins will return all the rows on the left side regardless if they exist on the right side

outer joins will return all rows of both sides

In your example, it's not clear which you prefer between left or outer, it's only clear you don't want inner.

Answer (score 0):

I think @jqurious is right, it is a left join:

```py
df1.join(df2, on="date", how="left", suffix="_β")
```

```
Out[31]: 
shape: (9, 5)
┌──────┬────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ type ┆ date       ┆ value ┆ type_β ┆ value_β │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str    ┆ i64     │
╞══════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 3     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 5     ┆ β      ┆ 666     │
│ A    ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 7     ┆ null   ┆ null    │
│ B    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 8     ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ B    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 9     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 12    ┆ β      ┆ 100     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 0     ┆ β      ┆ 233     │
│ C    ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1     ┆ β      ┆ 666     │
└──────┴────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┘
```

I hope he expands the answer, because he is right, I was looking at `cross` joins first, but it is a left-join.